# BottomSheetDialogFragment jumps on top of status bar, when any view's size changes or EditText receives focus

Tags: android, dialog, android-bottomsheetdialog

In my `BottomSheetDialogFragment` I use this option (`fitsSystemWindows = false`) to fix strange effect while scrolling to bottom [example gif](https://gfycat.com/organicorangegar) (`MapView` is on top of navigation bar)

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    (requireView().parent.parent.parent as View).fitsSystemWindows = false
  }
```

But than it causes another problem, when any `view's` size changes or `EditText` receives focus dialog height were jumped on top of status bar and navigation bar is also transparent
[example 2 gif](https://gfycat.com/tannearcrayfish)

Does anyone had the same problem or any idea how to fix this strange jumps

Comment: How did you apply the rounded corners? I tried lots of things until my code behaved right, i can share my code but best way is make sample project and see if my approach works there. I'm away from laptop now can't share code.

Comment: I'm using this setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyDialogStyle) 
( <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> ) than I have rounded corner shape drawable in my dialog layout

Comment: yep I think that's the reason. I tried something liike that too and didn't get the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in one of my projects. It will make all of your bottom sheet dialog fragments to have the same shape. And its contents will scroll without moving that shape.

Note that if your `AppTheme` inherits from a different theme your mileage may vary. Let me know if this doesn't do anything at all on your project, I have another project that may have a small variation on how this is done.

```
 <!--    https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/ -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.RoundedBottomSheet</item>


 </style>

<style name="AppTheme.RoundedBottomSheet" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Rounded corner is applied, but problem is same, dialog steel jumps on top of status bar when edittext receives focus

Comment: If I remove this line (requireView().parent.parent.parent as View).fitsSystemWindows = false than it stops jumping but than MapView is on top of navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

setting for all view in bottomSheetDialog `android:animateLayoutChanges=false` helped to me